# Java Web Crawler Libraries

Tags: java, web-crawler

I wanted to make a Java based web crawler for an experiment. I heard that making a Web Crawler in Java was the way to go if this is your first time. However, I have two important questions.

1. How will my program 'visit' or 'connect' to web pages? Please give a brief explanation. (I understand the basics of the layers of abstraction from the hardware up to the software, here I am interested in the Java abstractions)
2. What libraries should I use? I would assume I need a library for connecting to web pages, a library for HTTP/HTTPS protocol, and a library for HTML parsing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is How your program 'visit' or 'connect' to web pages.

```
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String line;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
         mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }
```

This will download source of html page.

For HTML parsing see [this](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

Also take a look at [jSpider](http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/) and [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: So, does this pull information from a page, or simply go to the page? I'm trying to write a crawler that will take user input, go to maps.google.com, plug in the address and take route time and route length and bring it back to the program. Is this possible?

Comment: @Adrian have a look at google maps api : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

Answer (score 15):

Crawler4j is the best solution for you,

[Crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) is an open source Java crawler which provides a simple interface for crawling the Web. You can setup a multi-threaded web crawler in 5 minutes!

Also [visit.](http://cuneytyesilkaya.blogspot.com/2012/01/web-crawler-tools.html) for more java based web crawler tools and brief explanation for each.

Answer (score 7):

Right now there is a inclusion of many java based HTML parser that support visiting and parsing the HTML pages.

- [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [Jaunt API](http://jaunt-api.com/)
- [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)
- [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)
- [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/)
- [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers) the complete list of HTML parser with basic comparison.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I have refined my answer now.

Comment: There is a difference between crawling and scraping. None of your examples can crawl the Net.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at these existing projects if you want to learn how it can be done:

- [Apache Nutch](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FrontPage#What_is_Apache_Nutch.3F)
- [crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j)
- [gecco](https://github.com/xtuhcy/gecco)
- [Norconex HTTP Collector](https://www.norconex.com/collectors/collector-http/flow)
- [vidageek crawler](https://github.com/vidageek/crawler)
- [webmagic](https://github.com/code4craft/webmagic)
- [Webmuncher](https://github.com/dadepo/Webmuncher)

A typical crawler process is a loop consisting of fetching, parsing, link extraction, and processing of the output (storing, indexing). Though the devil is in the details, i.e. how to be "polite" and respect `robots.txt`, meta tags, redirects, rate limits, URL canonicalization, infinite depth, retries, revisits, etc.

[image: Norconex HTTP Collector flow diagram]

<sup>*Flow diagram courtesy of [Norconex HTTP Collector](https://www.norconex.com/collectors/collector-http/flow).*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

For parsing content, I'm using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the [HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). You can found examples [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer crawler4j. Crawler4j is an open source Java crawler which provides a simple interface for crawling the Web. You can setup a multi-threaded web crawler in few hours.

Answer (score 2):

I think [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is better than others, jsoup runs on Java 1.5 and up, Scala, Android, OSGi, and Google App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

I come up with another solution to propose that no one mention. There is a library called [Selenum](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) it is is an open-source automating testing tool used for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to only this . You can write a web crawler and get benefited from this automation testing tool just as a human would do.

As an illustration, i will provide to you a quick tutorial to get a better look of how it works. if you are being bored to read this post take a look at this [Video](https://youtu.be/8YktQ-2Do1Q) to understand what capabilities this library can offer in order to crawl web pages.

### Selenium Components

To begin with Selenium consist of various components that coexisted in a unique process and perform their action on the java program. This main component is called Webdriver and it must be included in your program in order to make it working properly.

Go to the following [site](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) here and download the latest release for your computer OS (Windows, Linux, or MacOS). It is a ZIP archive containing chromedriver.exe. Save it on your computer and then extract it to a convenient location just as **C:\WebDrivers\User\chromedriver.exe** We will use this location later in the java program.

The next step is to inlude the jar library. Assuming you are using maven project to build the java programm you need to add the follow dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

### Selenium Web driver Setup

Let us get started with Selenium. The first step is to create a ChromeDriver instance:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\WebDrivers\User\chromedriver.exe);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Now its time to get deeper in code.The following example shows a simple programma that open a web page and extract some useful Html components. It is easy to understand, as it has comments that explain the steps clearly. Please take a brief look to understand how to capture the objects

```
//Launch website
      driver.navigate().to("http://www.calculator.net/");

      //Maximize the browser
      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      // Click on Math Calculators
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id = 'menu']/div[3]/a")).click();

      // Click on Percent Calculators
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id = 'menu']/div[4]/div[3]/a")).click();

      // Enter value 10 in the first number of the percent Calculator
      driver.findElement(By.id("cpar1")).sendKeys("10");

      // Enter value 50 in the second number of the percent Calculator
      driver.findElement(By.id("cpar2")).sendKeys("50");

      // Click Calculate Button
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id = 'content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[2]")).click();


      // Get the Result Text based on its xpath
      String result =
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id = 'content']/p[2]/font/b")).getText();


      // Print a Log In message to the screen
      System.out.println(" The Result is " + result);
```

Once you are done with your work, the browser window can be closed with:

```
driver.quit();
```

### Selenium Browser Options

There too much functionality you can implement when you working with this library, For example, assuming you are using chrome you can add in your code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
```

Take look at how we can use WebDriver to open Chrome extensions using ChromeOptions

```
options.addExtensions(new File("src\test\resources\extensions\extension.crx"));
```

This is for using Incognito mode

```
options.addArguments("--incognito");
```

this one for disabling javascript and info bars

```
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-javascript");
```

this one if you want to make the browser scraping silently and hide browser crawling in the background

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

once you have done with it then

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

To sum up let's see what Selenium has to offer and make it a unique choice compared with the other solutions that proposed on this post thus far.

- Language and Framework Support
- Open Source Availability
- Multi-Browser Support
- Support Across Various Operating Systems
- Ease Of Implementation
- Reusability and Integrations
- Parallel Test Execution and Faster Go-to-Market
- Easy to Learn and Use
- Constant Updates

Comment: i've recived nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore.apache droid or apache nutch to  get the feel of java based crawler

Answer (score 0):

Though mainly used for Unit Testing web applications, HttpUnit traverses a website, clicks links, analyzes tables and form elements, and gives you meta data about all the pages.  I use it for Web Crawling, not just for Unit Testing. - http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of available crawler:

https://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers

But I suggest using [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/)