# How to get all links from google

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, google-search

I am trying to get all of the links to the songs on the side of google after you search for the band and album ex:
https://www.google.com/search?q=disturbed+asylum&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

So I have tried quite a bit on my own. I've used:

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

and then printed out all of the links, but it didn't get the links to the side this way. I then tried to get the html code and then search for the table through there but it didn't pull the table for some reason. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has been asked here : [java crawlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282503/java-web-crawler-libraries)

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I already have a way that gets the html code, the thing is for some reason it might be counting that right half of google as a different section because the table doesnt show up there and it doesnt grab the links

Comment: So you cannot extract links?

Comment: I can get a list of links but its not giving me the links in the table i mentioned

Comment: try using xpath, you can access you element knowing the class name of it, so in your case it would be `xpath("//div[@class=\"someclass\""]`

Comment: [related article](http://xmlquerying.blogspot.com/2012/12/declarative-crawling-with-java.html)