# reading from websites with java

Tags: java

I am developing a program that can read data from the following website in java:

https://nz.finance.yahoo.com/world-indices

In java how do I read data from the website?
I am thinking I will want to store it in an array list, is this correct and how do I make sure it is doing that? also once I am reading from this website, how do I make sure it is reading and only reading the information I am looking for?

thanks

Comment: If the website has API for get data you can use API，or you mustdownload the HTML and parse

Comment: may be you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282503/java-web-crawler-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Once you begin looking into other websites for input, it can get quite tricky. Now since I am only a senior in High School in Comp Sci 4, I cannot give you a GREAT amount direction, but I did some poking around on Oracle and found this web page, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html . I am not exactly sure how to narrow down data types, but I hope I get you in the right direction.

Comment: ye i had found this before, ill give it a try

Comment: I think this should be a comment same as Erwin did above instead a post. (I know that you can't add a comment yet.)